# costomize elements on responsive navbar when it become to a dropdown. bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello i want to make a responsive navbar but i dont know how to edit it when its on a small screen mode
(like on a mobile or a tablet)
here is how it looks in
[rgeular size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvqC5.png)

and here is on a
[small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqTcp.png)

and whati want to do is when the screen is small i want to have text beside the icon
and i want the search bar to be the first in the list and also i want it to fit in only one row and not 2 (see picture).

here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'index' %}">
                          <!--home-->
                          <i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                          <!--explore-->
                          <i class="far fa-compass fa-lg"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!--search-->
                  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
      
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'add_movie' %}">
                          <!-- Add -->
                          <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                          <!-- Log out -->
                          <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-lg"></i>
                         </a>
                  </li>
                    
                  </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the search bar to be in one row, try this:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
   <div class="row">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-sm-8" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0 col-sm-4" type="submit">Search</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Just mess around with the col-sm class numbers until you get them right.